# Why wrong routes are getting applied in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET CORE MVC project. Which has 2 routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "news",
       template: "News{controller}/{action}");
});
```

---

> I noticed that in CORE 2.0 Framework the concept of defining specific
>   routes at first do not apply for my 2 routes shown above. Is there a Bug? or there something wrong with my code?

---

When the URL - **'/NewsHome/Index'** is fetched it is calling the Home Controller Action method.

It should **actually call the NewsHome Controller's Index method**. What is wrong ?

> I am also giving an extract from the book - 'Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2 by
>   Adam Freeman' to make my point. Please see below:

[image]

what is wrong, please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

It's behaving exactly as explained in the book. Just invert the order of your routes.

Comment: I don't want to change the order of routes. The whole question is about the wrong routes getting called.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken the right route is getting called:
"Then the first route, which matches any URL with zero, one, or two segments, will ALWAYS be the one that is used"
this '/NewsHome/Index' is a two segments URL then it calls  your first route.
 so "as a consequence, the most specific routes must be defined first."

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the screenshot you posted. You should reverse the order of the mappings. In the screenshot it's showing how it would be wrong.

Comment: My question is that If the order of route is kept same as what i posted then the url '/NewsHome/Index' should be calling the 'NewsHome' Controller (based on 1st route). But it is not. It is actually calling 'Home' controller as second route is applied. why?

Comment: Do you have an actual controller, called "NewsHome"?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "news",
   template: "News{controller}/{action}");
```

TO

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "news",
   template: "/news/{action}");
```

Comment: i don't mean that. My routes are correct but i think asp.net core is behaving differently.